# MongoDb aggregate on nested object field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a collection of documents of format

```
{
    "name": <name>,
    "status": {
        "statusId": <can be a number which I want to aggregate like 1/2/3/4>
    }
}
```

I want to have an aggregation by `status.statusId` - e.g. 5 documents have `status.statusId` = 0, 3 documents have `status.statusId` = 5 etc.

I tried

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate([
{
    $group: { _id: { "status":  { "statusId": "$statusId" }}, count: {$sum:1} }
}
])
```

but it doesn't work.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the dot notation for your _id

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate([
   {
      $group: { _id:  "$status.statusId", count: {$sum:1} }
   }
])
```